# Get Text from EditText after certain position

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, position

I'm trying to get the text of an EditText after a certain position. For example, if I had an EditText and loaded the text "Hello" (i.e. `.setText("Hello");`) inside, it would look like:

```
Hello
```

Then If i typed "Hi" it would look like..

```
HelloHi
```

Is there away to use getText to just return ("Hi"). I.e. getText after `.length() == 5`, or something like that!

I hope there is a solution for this, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this to your code.I stored the string in variable a after the indexing 5. you may change the textfield with the place from were you are getting the text.

```
String a = TextField.getText().subString(5);//you may change the place to gettext
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 inputEditText.addTextChangedListener(watch);
```

Add Text Watcher and watcher as follows:

```
TextWatcher watch = new TextWatcher(){
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
      int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int a, int b, int c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    output.setText(s);
    if(s.length()>5){
String string =s.subString(5,s.length());
inputEditText.setText(string);
}
    }
  }};
```

Comment: Modify accordingly based on your requirement.

Comment: What is subString declared as?

Comment: Substring is taken from 5th character to rest of the string. Its just eliminating first 5 characters

Answer (score 0):

Well you have inbuilt methods for edittext like

if say editText1 is view that you have declared

```
editText1.getText().getChars(start, end, dest, destoff);
```

or for a character

```
editText1.getText().getCharAt(index);
```